# Spring component scan doesn't load its own components if I change basePackages?

Tags: spring-boot, component-scan

I'm trying to get started with Spring Boot so I can use it in my future projects.

However after I implemented my "authentication" library which contains some simple user service (implementation of `UserDetailsService`), I tried to integrate that into my new Spring Boot app.

Because the `UserService` is in a separate JAR, I had to change the base packages that Spring looks into so they get loaded.

Everything it's fine, my app starts, endpoints work as expected. I get redirected to login and I try to log in with my user from the database. Here the problem pops up. I get `No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

After digging around I found out that if remove the base package classes to scan and use the inmemory UserDetailService everything works as expected. I want to use the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` which should just use my `UserDetailService` implementation.

Can it be that Spring doesn't load this anymore when I change `basePackages` or I'm missing something else?

You can see what I tried here: (don't worry code is in Scala, I'm just evaluating how they work together)

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = Array("ro.sandd", "spring.framework"))
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = Array("ro.sandd"))
@EntityScan(basePackages = Array("ro.sandd"))
class SpringDemoApplication

object SpringDemoApplication extends App {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[SpringDemoApplication]);
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@Import(Array(classOf[UserService]))
//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Array(classOf[UserService], classOf[DaoAuthenticationProvider]))
class WebSecurityConfig(@Autowired val userService: UserService) extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with Logging {

  protected override def configure(http: HttpSecurity): Unit = {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/demo").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .permitAll();
  }

  @Bean
  override def userDetailsService: UserDetailsService = {
    userService
  }
}
```

Also I have some simple Controller but I don't think it's worth to see the code. Also ... I probably can provide a custom provider, but my purpose is to use the existing one as for me it seems suitable.

**PS Further investigation 1:**

Note 1 - If I use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = Array(classOf[UserService]))` I can see the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` loaded into `AuthenticationConfiguration`. But my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` config method is not called. Instead, the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$DefaultConfigurerAdapter` gets used.

Note 2 - If I use @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = Array(classOf[UserService], classOf[WebSecurityConfig])) to force the load of my `WebSecurityConfig`, authenticationProviders list is empty.

So it must be some problem when this WebSecurityConfig actually gets used. However... I'm wondering how my `UserDetailsService` was working if this class wasn't used. That's where I provided it as you can see bellow. Probably Spring did some magic and injected it somewhere else.

```
 @Bean
  override def userDetailsService: UserDetailsService = {
    userService
  }
```

**PS Further investigation 2:**

I removed the @Bean declaration above and everything works as expected. Probably the fact that I already Autowire my UserService is enough for Spring to inject it where it has to.

Anyway, some explanation why it doesn't work when I use the override method would be useful.

Comment: Stop using classpath scanning for libraries - that way madness lies. Build an autoconfiguration.

Comment: One thing I just noticed/remembered... If I use basePackages I get the same behavior (no default authenticationprovider). If I switch to `scanBasePackageClasses` my userService it's used, does the authentication (default authentication provider woks) but I have trouble with HttpSecurity (somehow not taken into consideration)

Comment: If I remove the overriding of userDetailsService, everything works and also Spring somehow also injects my class of UserDetailService. Wicked